# How to remove all elements?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function main() {
    const URL_SCREENSHOT =
     'https://www.placardefutebol.com.br/brasileirao-serie-a/12-11-2022-flamengo-x-avai.html'
  
     const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        userDataDir: './logs/Chrome/XX',
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
        ]
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(URL_SCREENSHOT, {
      waitUntil: "load",
      timeout: 0,
    });
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > div.google-auto-placed > ins").remove()`);
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > header").remove()`);
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > nav").remove()`);
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("html > ins").remove()`);
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("#google_esf").remove()`);
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > iframe").remove()`);
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > ins").remove()`);
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(13)").remove()`);
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(12)").remove()`);
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(11)").remove()`);
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(10)").remove()`); 
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(9)").remove()`);           
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(8)").remove()`);           
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(7)").remove()`);           
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > link").remove()`);              
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script").remove()`);            
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > p:nth-child(4)").remove()`);            
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > p").remove()`);             
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > div > div.jumbotron").remove()`);           
      await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > div > div.search-box").remove()`);
      

      await page.screenshot({path: `./lib/media/img/adip.png`, fullPage: true })
      await browser.close()
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  main();
```

I wanted some way to remove all the elements listed above *(await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("x").remove()`);)* one by one, and if it doesn't find any element it ignores instead of giving error, does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: You could use `try{ document.querySelector('...').remove(); } catch (e){}`

Answer (score 0):

**For Puppeteer with Newer Browsers**

Use a nullish coalescer operator:

```
await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > div.google-auto-placed > ins")?.remove()`);
```

For example, applied to your code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function main() {
    const URL_SCREENSHOT =
        'https://www.placardefutebol.com.br/brasileirao-serie-a/12-11-2022-flamengo-x-avai.html'

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        userDataDir: './logs/Chrome/XX',
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
        ]
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(URL_SCREENSHOT, {
        waitUntil: "load",
        timeout: 0,
    });
    setTimeout(async () => {
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > div.google-auto-placed > ins")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > header")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > nav")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("html > ins")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("#google_esf")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > iframe")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > ins")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(13)")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(12)")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(11)")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(10)")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(9)")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(8)")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script:nth-child(7)")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > link")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > script")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > p:nth-child(4)")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > p")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > div > div.jumbotron")?.remove()`);
        await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector("body > div > div.search-box")?.remove()`);


        await page.screenshot({
            path: `./lib/media/img/adip.png`,
            fullPage: true
        })
        await browser.close()
    }, 1000);
}

main();
```

**For Puppeteer with Older Browsers**

You can try using code generation:

```
const selectors = ["body > div.google-auto-placed > ins", ...]

for (const selector of selectors) {
  await page.evaluate(`if (document.querySelector("${selector}")) document.querySelector("${selector}").remove()`);
}
```